# Quickhull - all points on convex hull - bad performance

Tags: performance, computational-geometry, convex-hull

How to avoid bad performance in quickhull algorithm, when all points in input lie on convex hull?

Comment: Do you know in advance (I.E. before you run quickhull) that all points are going to be in the hull?

Comment: Complexity of QuickHull algorithm doesn't depend (directly) on the percentage of points on convex hull (what is observed for gift wrapping algorithm, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickHull's performance comes mainly from being able to throw away a portion of the input with each recursive call (or iteration). This does not happen when all the points lie on a circle, unfortunately. Even in this case, it's still possible to obtain an *O(nlog n)* worst-case performance if the split step gives a fairly balanced partition at every recursive call. The ultimate worst-case which results in quadratic runtime is when we have grossly imbalanced splits (say one split always ends up empty) in each call. Because this pretty much depends on the dataset, there's not much one can do about it.

You might want to try other algorithms instead, such as [Andrew's variant of Graham's scan](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain), or [MergeHull](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/divideandconquer.html). Both have guaranteed *O(nlog n)* worst-case time-complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For some algorithm implementation comparison, I suggest to look at my article: [Fast and improved 2D Convex Hull algorithm and its implementation in O(n log h)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210225/Fast-and-improved-D-Convex-Hull-algorithm-and-its) which compare many 2D algorithm performance like:

- Monotone chain
- Graham scan
- Delaunay/Voronoi
- Chan
- Liu and Chen
- Ouellet (mine)